# Using DATE ADD with INSERT prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'd like to know if its possible and/or sensible to use DATE_ADD with a prepared statement in PHP. I have a number of variables I'm passing to PHP that I want to insert, one is a SQL format datetime and the other is the same datetime but I want to add a number of days to it. The number of days is also held in a variable passed to PHP.. Here's my query so far

```
$mySql="INSERT INTO delay (delayBookID, delayEED0, delayEDD1, delayDDC, delayUserID, delayCreated) 
VALUE (?,?,DATE_ADD(?,? DAY),?,?,NOW())";
```

to clarify: here my bind param

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $bookID, $edd0, $edd1, $xD4Book, $ddc, $userID);
```

Can anyone help??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DATE_ADD` in an INSERT statement, however, you are missing the key word INTERVAL in `DATE_ADD`.

It should be `DATE_ADD(?, INTERVAL ? DAY)`

Comment: thanks for your help. yYou're right missed the 'interval' but now I struggling with a falied to bindparam. I've bee looking at this for hours and I can see where I'm going wrong. The vars for the date_add would have normally been: DATE__ADD($edd0, INTERVAL $xD4Book DAY)... Am I not using the correct number of 's' declarations in my bind_param?? your thoughts??

Comment: I've solved via my own question to you, need to add and extra 's' and restate the variable I wanted to place in the DATE_ADD... Totally new to this prepared statements and my brain is fizzing trying  to get my head around it... Thanks for your help ... Your answer put me on the right path...

Comment: happy you figured it out. its always more satisfying that way.